# How to fix POST data not properly set from ajax request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem in getting the POST data from a page using ajax. In the jquery code the data is running smoothly and it will display when i alert the data. In the ajax request code the data from jquery has been successfully pass into **showpercent.php** file. Now the problem about **showpercent.php**, the data POST index **percentage_id** is unidentified. How can i fix this problem in getting the value of POST?

Below is the table list with button when the data is coming from.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info show-percentage" title="Click to add view percentages!" data-percentage_id="'.$row['hidden_id'] .'" data-toggle="show-percentage"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Below is the ajax request sending the data into **showpercent.php** file. When I alert the **percentage_id** from button click the data will show in the alert and the ajax was successfully pass into specific php file which is **showpercent.php**.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".show-percentage").click(function(){

    var percentage_id = $(this).data('percentage_id');

    alert("Ajax Landing ID "+landing_id);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/showpercent.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: { percentage_id : percentage_id },

        success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
          $('#add-percentage').modal('show');
          readRecords();
        },
        error: function(request, status, error){
          alert("Error!! "+error);
        }             
    });

    // READ recods when the button is click
    readRecords();
  });

  function readRecords() {
    $.get("ajax/showpercent.php", {}, function (data, status) {
      $(".display_percentage").html(data);
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Below is the modal having a tab will display the data from ajax request. The class **display_percentage** will display the current data from **showpercentage**.

```
<div id="add-percentage" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Fish Landing Percentage</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Add Percentage</a></li>
          </ul>

          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
              <br>
              <div class="display_percentage"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" id="primary" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddPercentage()"> Add Percentage </button>
              <button type="button" id="danger" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**showpercent.php**

This file will read by **readRecords()** function to display into the modal with tab class **display_percentage** when the button click is triggered.

This is now the problem comes, when the data was successfully pass from ajax request the data POST in the **showpercent.php** is not properly set and cannot proceed to the mysql process because the POST is not set.

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

$data = '
  <table">
      <thead>
          <tr class="success">
            <th ><center>No.</center></th>
            <th ><center>Percentage ID</center></th>
            <th ><center>Landing ID</center></th>
            <th><center>Percentage</center></th>
            <th><center>Date Added</center></th>
          </tr>
      </thead>';

if(isset($_POST['percentage_id'])){

  $landing_id = $_POST['percentage_id'];
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT
              percentage.percent_id,
              percentage.landing_id,
              percentage.percentage,
              percentage.date_recorded
              FROM
              percentage
              WHERE percentage.landing_id = '$landing_id'");

  $number = 1;

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    $data .= '
      <tr>
        <td><center>' . $number . '</center></td>
        <td><center>' . $row['percent_id'] . '</center></td>
        <td><center>' . $row['landing_id'] . '</center></td>
        <td><center>' . $row['percentage'] . '%</center></td>
        <td><center>' . date("M. d, Y", strtotime($row['date_recorded'])) . '</center></td>
      </tr>';
    $number++;
  }
}else{
  echo 'Percentage id is not set!';
}
  $data .= '
  </table>';

echo $data;
?>
```

But in the console the ajax passing data will run smoothly.

I wish anybody will help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Where is the element with class `show-percentage` ? Since the ajax was bound to click event of elements with that class.

Comment: @user3647971 I already updated the code.

Comment: I think  you need to use like that data-percentage_id="<?php echo $row['hidden_id'];  ?>"

Comment: WHERE percentage.landing_id =$landing_id");  ,I think you have a MySQL error and not a php error , remove the single quotes around variable

Comment: you mean `percentage_id` is undefined inside your php? whats the result when you `console.log(percentage_id);`?

Comment: isn't that should be `var percentage_id = $(this).attr('data-percentage_id');` instead

Comment: And what do you get with `print_r($_POST)` at the very start of your PHP ?  You may also want to see if your input is in `php://input`

Comment: @Osama it will give an error to me when i remove the single quotes.

Comment: and `data-percentage_id="<?php echo $row['hidden_id']  ?>"`

Comment: @Beginner yes bro the index of the POST is undefined, it will display nothing.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: @ivanivan it will display array().

Comment: If you are getting an empty `$_POST` array then check `print(file_get_contents("php://input"))` - it may be a json string, in which case just `json_decode` it

Comment: @Osama mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: @ivanivan why its always data 1 will get in the print(file_get_contents("php://input")) its not the data from the ajax will pass.. what is the problem of this?

Comment: Can't tell wihtout seeing. Edit and update this question, or close it out and post a new one.  Remember - the more useful detail you add, the better.  It avoids 20 comments asking for clarification and what output you get on basic print-to-debug type stuff.

Comment: You are assigning the value to `percentage_id` but the value you're showing in the `alert()` is `landing_id` ... so whatever you think you're seeing in the `alert()` isn't what you're `POST`ing via the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

try:
add this in your html

```
<button id="percentage_id" class="btn btn-info show-percentage" title="Click to add view percentages!" data-percentage_id="<?=$row['hidden_id'] ?>" data-toggle="show-percentage"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></button>
```

set the value of your percentage_id before getting it

add to your JavaScript with

```
$("#percentage_id]").data('percentage_id',loading_id); //setter
var percentage_id = $(this).data('percentage_id'); //getter
```

Comment: so he should set the data this way $("#percentage_id]").data('percentage_id',loading_id); before getting it.

Answer (score 0):

I read your code your showpercent.php, javascript and html and soo far and notice this

```
<button class="btn btn-info show-percentage" title="Click to add view percentages!" data-percentage_id="'.$row['hidden_id'] .'" data-toggle="show-percentage"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></button>
```

and check this

```
data-percentage_id="'.$row['hidden_id'] .'"
```

you're doing it wrong this is not how you put php value into html value, this will return undefined in javascript if you try to get its value so

This is why

```
var percentage_id = $(this).data('percentage_id');
```

returns undefined in javascript and php

So replace it with this

```
data-percentage_id="<?php echo $row['hidden_id']; ?>"
```

So replace your button into like this

```
<button class="btn btn-info show-percentage" title="Click to add view percentages!" data-percentage_id="<? echo $row['hidden_id']; ?>" data-toggle="show-percentage"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></button>
```

thanks to @Keval Mangukiya